# indexing through graphQL by a string, instead of ID in React/Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a read-only stack of data that I cannot add an ID to. Therefore the only unique identifier I can use is a field "name". I was able to retrieve the data ok on a normal list screen. When I click on one of the items, it Routes to a page using that same identifier to name that screen (subfix the URL). Here's a sample of the query.

```
const ORDERS_QUERY = gql`
  query pizzaShop {
    pizzaSizes {
      name
      maxToppings
      basePrice
      toppings {
        defaultSelected
        topping {
          name
          price
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

When I query that with this (and having Routes imported of course). I do go to a new page localhost/name-here

```
<Query query={ORDERS_QUERY}>
      {({ loading, error, data }) => {
        if (loading) return <h4>Loading...</h4>;
        if (error) console.log('error');
        return (
          <div className='pizza-sizes'>
            {data.pizzaSizes.map(pizzaSizes => (
               <Link key={pizzaSizes.name} to={`/pizzaSize/${name}`}>
                  <button>{name}</button>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }}
</Query>
```

Now, here is the thing I'm having problems with. This new page that opens is supposed to show the props from that item only. So, bringing in the query for the stuff that needs to show on this page, here's the new query of items from GgraphQL. See Below. I normally do this with an id just fine, like this:

```
const SINGLE_ITEM_QUERY = gql`
    query sample($id: Int!) {
       parent(id: $id) {
          ...data here
       }
    }
`;

 //in render method...
 let { id } = this.props.match.params;
 id = parseInt(id); //becasue it may be saved as a string
```

However, in this case the unique identifier is a string. but I'm getting nothing with this below, zilch, potatoes

```
const TOPPINGS_QUERY = gql`
    query orderQuery($name: String!) {
        pizzaSizes(name: $name) {                
           maxToppings
           basePrice
           toppings {
              defaultSelected
              topping {
                 name
                 price
              }
           }
        }
    }
`;
```

what am I missing? I wish I could give a demo but there is a lot of component dependency tying other stuff together that will just confuse this even more

Comment: Need some clarification before this question can be tackled. Is your query going through and just returning `null`, or are there one or more errors returned by the server? Is `name` a valid argument for the `pizzaSizes` field? If it's a valid argument and the server is just returning null, then that sounds like an issue with the server code.

Comment: As an aside, if you're already fetching a list of items from the server with all the necessary fields, you probably don't need to make a separate single item query on top of that. You can either reuse the same query and just filter the results down to the item you need, or at the very least use [query redirects](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/performance#cache-redirects)

Comment: @DanielRearden I'm taking over from somebody else's work, there are calls to this graphQL for different things from different places, as opposed to one call and reducers. I was hoping to fix it without re-writing too much. I'll see what else I can do. Thanks